# colorbox shows "Request unsuccessful: error" on chrome

Tags: colorbox

I am trying to load content from a html page on my colorbox when my page is ready, using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.colorbox({href:"popup.html",'width':'750px', 'height':'700px'});  
});
```

It works fine on every browser but chrome, which shows in the colorbox popup "Request unsuccessful: error". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok I found the solution, it seems that adding iframe:true fixes this issue for chrome, so: $.fn.colorbox({iframe:true,href:"popup.html",'width':'750px', 'height':'700px'});